# Restricting Permissions on MySites - Retrospectively

Tags: 2013, permissions, my-site, mysites

After 6 months my client wants to limit 'Visitors' permissions (Read) in their MySites. They want to remove their ability to create subsites, create apps, upload documents etc in MySites. This is possible for new MySites through 'User Profile Synchronization' in central admin.  What's the best way to do this change retrospectively to sites that already exist?

- I'm assuming with Powershell, but as all users are site collection administrators of their own MySites they automatically have full control of their site. Any changes to the users permissions in Mysites Site Collection  won't have any affect.

Comment: Using PowerShell get a list of My Sites collection and its respective Admin's. Then go and remove them using PowerShell. Add them to the respective groups.

Comment: By default, visitors to a mysite have none of those permissions. You are mixing 2 different things in this, the actual mysite owner (a SCA) and a visitor. Please clarify what you mean, as is, it is unanswerable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Our 'Intranet Visitors' group has read only to the Intranet site collection, but they can create document libraries, lists and subsites on their own MySites (by default). My client wants this restricted after an audit they had. So all of my clients users are site collection administrators of their own MySites (my/personal/). I hope that's clearer?